# How to import external module/dependencies like Flic in my Android project which is using Bazel as build system?

Tags: java, android, bazel

For importing module dependency in my Android project, for ex. For making my app compatible with Flic I have to import the whole Flic project as module dependency in my existing Android project. It works fine when built with gradle but with Bazel it shows error while importing any class of Flic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Flic, but looking at the [instructions here](https://partners.flic.io/partners/developers/android-tutorial), it looks like flic can be depended upon using `http_archive` and writing a small `android_library` rule for it:

`WORKSPACE`:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
  name = "flic-android",
  # latest commit as of writing this answer
  url = "https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/fliclib-android/archive/ddfbfebfd5090bb2cc80a7e66c613134ffc4071a.zip",
  build_file = "@//:BUILD.flic-android",
  strip_prefix = "fliclib-android-ddfbfebfd5090bb2cc80a7e66c613134ffc4071a"
)
```

`BUILD.flic-android` (put this next to the `WORKSPACE` file):

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

android_library(
  name = "flic",
  manifest = "fliclib/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
  srcs = glob(["fliclib/src/main/java/io/flic/lib/*.java"]),

  idl_srcs =        glob(["fliclib/src/main/aidl/io/flic/lib/*.aidl"]),
  # "external/flic-android" must be included in the import root because this
  # rule is being evaluated in an external repository
  idl_import_root = "external/flic-android/fliclib/src/main/aidl",

  custom_package = "io.flic.lib",
)
```

Finally, add `"@flic-android//:flic"` to the `deps` of any `android_binary` or `android_library` rules that use Flic.

(Side note: flic's [`build.gradle` file](https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/fliclib-android/blob/ddfbfebfd5090bb2cc80a7e66c613134ffc4071a/fliclib/build.gradle#L23) listed `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1` as a compile-time dependency, but it doesn't appear to be needed to compile the library, so I didn't include that here)